# How to change cursor icon in editable area dynamically in CKEditor (IE issue)?

Tags: ckeditor

IE 'contenteditable' implemntation is not allowing me to change the cursor property when ever the contenteditable property in CKEditor is set to 'true'(no issue if the contenteditable='false').

Not an issue in chrome in both cases whether the contenteditable is set to true/false.

tried to change it dynamically using the following code but was not successful

```
var element = $('iframe').contents().find('body.cke_show_borders').get(0);
var elem = CKEDITOR.dom.element.get( element );
elem.setStyle('cursor', 'pointer');
```

any idea to handle this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is browser native bug.
You can reproduce this issue outside of CKEDITOR with following code:

```
<body style="cursor:pointer" contenteditable="true">
</body>
```

I doubt there are any workarounds for this.